# How to get a context menu for edit boxes within WIX 3.6?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, contextmenu, wix3.5, wix3.6

I was looking through a bug reported with some of my work's installer code yesterday and found that right click doesn't open a context menu for any of our installers.

The context menu is displayed for password boxes, so paste of me thinks it's a setting I missed when ploughing through the documentation, but I've not seen anything on google.

Is it a bug? Missing setting or a design feature?

Code is very simple and like this:

(Working Case: Password Box)

```
 <Control Id="Label2" Type="Text" X="15" Y="123" Width="85" Height="18" Transparent="yes" Text="Password:" />
 <Control Id="Edit2" Type="Text" Password="yes" X="100" Y="120" Width="235" Height="18" Property="PASSWORD" Text="[PASSWORD]" ToolTip="The password for the activation service to register the application." />
```

(Failing Case: Edit or Text Box)

```
  <Control Id="Label1" Type="Text" X="15" Y="103" Width="80" Height="18" Transparent="yes" Text="Username:" />
  <Control Id="Edit1" Type="Edit" X="100" Y="100" Width="235" Height="18" Property="ACTIVATIONUSERNAME" Text="[ACTIVATIONUSERNAME]" ToolTip="The username for the activation service to register the application." />
```

Cheers,
J

P.S I checked WIX 3.5 and the same issue seems to occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen many times that MSI wizard does not have context menu in edit boxes. I guess it's the bug (or the feature) of Windows Installer. It subclasses all standard controls, i.e. changes their WndProc to new one, and in this case it may block context menu from appearing, perhaps unintentionally.